# Set camunda business key

Tags: grails, camunda

I'm currently working on a project with camunda integrated. I was able to create a process instance, and everything else. But now I have to set the value of the **businessKey**. Does somebody know if there is any endpoint to do that? I'm working with **grails5** and I have to do every call to the camunda by **url**

Comment: Which REST API are you using to start the process?

Comment: @pme I'm using grails, as I said

Comment: yes I know;), and because of that you will need to use the Camunda REST API - see the answer of @rob2universe

Answer (score 1):

Full API documentation: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.17/reference/rest/

You would normally set the business key when the process instance is started:
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.17/reference/rest/process-definition/post-start-process-instance/
e.g.

```
{
 "variables":{
   "aVariable" : {
     "value" : "aStringValue",
     "type": "String"},
   "anotherVariable" : {
     "value" : true,
     "type": "Boolean",
     "valueInfo" : {
        "transient" : true
      }
    }
 },
 "businessKey" : "myBusinessKey",
 "withVariablesInReturn": true
}
```

You can also set the business key at other stages of the process, for instance in a scrip[t task or in expressions.

Comment: a small remark: you can only set the Business Key within the first Transaction.

Comment: Sorry, pme, I don't think that is correct. It should be set as early as possible, but there is no technical limitation. I have a process which uses a service task with a JavaDelegate and async before enabled. This JavaDelegate can set the buisness key, even though it is not running in the first transaction. Or maybe I misunderstood your comment...

Comment: no - I really thought I experienced this behaviour - maybe it is only the case when set in a Listener as described here: https://camunda.com/blog/2018/10/business-key/ (Workaround 1)